# Slow Wi-Fi connection

Tags: wireless

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.10 on my laptop. I tried to install the LTS version first but the wi fi wouldn't work. Now after I updated my Linux it works but very slow(max 400 kb/s speed when on Windows 10 I have 3-4 mb/s).Sometimes the wi fi on Linux stops randomly and i got very bad signal even near my router. Any advice?

Laptop: Kiano Elegance 14.2
OS: Ubuntu 18.10
SSD 120 GB
Dual Boot with windows 10 pro
4GB Ram
It doesn't have ethernet only Wifi, ironically I used an usb wi fi adapter to connect firstly to wifi to update linux beacuse otherwise the wifi wouldn't work

`sudo lshw -C Network`

```
  *-network                
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:7
       logical name: wlxac35ee58886a
       serial: ac:35:ee:58:88:6a
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=4.18.0-15-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.191 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

```
:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1122:3341  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b720 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: please edit your question and add the output of the following two commands: `lspci -knn` and `sudo lshw -C Network`

Comment: lshw -C Network:   https://imgur.com/a/W09FBTT

Comment: lspci -knn:  https://imgur.com/gallery/rL7PnrR

Comment: lscpi -knn: https://imgur.com/gallery/Ipt2yUq

Comment: please edit your question and append the output to it using <pre> </pre> tags or linking it to pastebin.com/  simply copy and paste the output of the terminal. unfortunately i cannot read the content of your compressed jpeg files with my tablet.

Comment: unfortunately i can't paste it in here beacuse the output is too long. How come you can't you use a browser on your tablet? It's a link on imgur not a jpg file

Comment: i dont know why my tablet is not able to open your img. instead ofmoosting the output here u can use pastebin.com

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ayn3qEM2

Comment: unfortunately i have problems to identify your wifi card from `lspci -knn`. regarding to `lshw` the driver u use is related to realtek `rtl8xxxu`. whats the out of `modinfo -F parm rtl8xxxu` and `lsmod` and `lsusb`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/r3jqcTaT

Answer (score 0):

What you could try:

1. **unload the driver and reload it with different antenna settings:** https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412761 or https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=237619 posting 23

   - `sudo modpobe -rv rtl8xxxu && sudo modprobe -v rtl8xxxu ant_sel=1`or
   - `sudo modpobe -rv rtl8xxxu && sudo modprobe -v rtl8xxxu ant_sel=2`or
   - `sudo modpobe -rv rtl8xxxu && sudo modprobe -v rtl8xxxu ant_sel=0`or
2. **unload the driver and load a different one**: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/drivers-installed-wifi-card-still-uses-the-generic-rtl8xxxu-4175622767/#post5813975

   - `sudo modprobe -rv rtl8xxxu && sudo modprobe -v rtl8723au`
3. **one last option could be to install and compile a driver from here** https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723bu

Comment: it says that rtl8xxu module couldn't be found

Comment: it's strange that if I use my mobile to hotspot the wifi works normally but on other wifi networks it sometimes works for a short period of time or sometimes it doesn't

Comment: i did write wrong, you have triple x (rtl8xxxu) but i wrote with double x (rlt8xxu).